# How to make paragraph with prefix icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

It is the same as the title.

I want to make a paragraph

When moving to the next line, there should be a space like the picture below..

image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/izB97.png

help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a many ways you can achieve the result. Please see the code below, I've demonstrated two ways possible (1) create your own Custom Widget (2) use the [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown/) package by Google team.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Paragraph Demo"),
        ),
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 0,
              child: Text(
                "Custom Widget",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: RowParagraph(text: '''
This is the first list item. This is the first list item. This is the first list item. This is the first list item. This is the first list item. This is the first list item.
Here's the second list item. Here's the second list item. Here's the second list item. Here's the second list item. Here's the second list item. Here's the second list item. 
And here's the third list item. And here's the third list item. And here's the third list item. And here's the third list item. And here's the third list item. And here's the third list item. 
              '''),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 0,
              child: Text(
                "Markdown Widget",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: MarkdownParagraph(text: '''
*   This is the first list item. This is the first list item. This is the first list item. This is the first list item. This is the first list item. This is the first list item.
*   Here's the second list item. Here's the second list item. Here's the second list item. Here's the second list item. Here's the second list item. Here's the second list item. 
*   And here's the third list item. And here's the third list item. And here's the third list item. And here's the third list item. And here's the third list item. And here's the third list item. 
              '''),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowParagraph extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const RowParagraph({Key key, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < text.split("\n").length - 1; i++) ...[
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                child: Text("•"),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  text.split("\n")[i],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
        ],
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MarkdownParagraph extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const MarkdownParagraph({Key key, this.text}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Markdown(
      styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet(
        p: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      data: text,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple class like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Paragraph extends StatelessWidget {
    Paragraph(this.items);
    final List<ParagraphItem> items;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var elements = <Widget>[];
        for (var item in items) {
            elements.add(item);
            elements.add(SizedBox(height: 10.0));
        }

        return Column(children: elements);
   } 
}

class ParagraphItem extends StatelessWidget {
    ParagraphItem(this.text, this.icon);
    final String text;
    final Icon icon;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: 
               CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
               icon,
               Expanded(
                  child: Text(text),
               ),
          ],
        );
     }
  }
```

Then add a new paragraph:

```
Paragraph([
    ParagraphItem('Example text', Icon(Icons.mail)),
])
```

Comment: However, the location of the prefix is ​​not correct.
It should be right in the middle of the first row, but it's too upward.

Comment: if you assign the CrossAxisAlignment.center property, the prefix moves to the center of the paragraph when the line breaks.

Comment: With CrossAxisAlignment.start should be fixed!

Comment: But if I modify it with CrossAxisAlignment.start it is not in the center.
It is located slightly above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how long your paragraph will be but you can check: [ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)